# Reshaping data for input tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

My input data is from a .csv file with 2 columns, and 5000 rows.

My input details from `input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()` gives me:

```
[{'name': 'serving_default_dense_8_input:0',
  'index': 0,
  'shape': array([1, 2], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([-1,  2], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

When I run the following line: `interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 4999 but expected 1 for dimension 0 of input 0.
```

And I am really not sure what this means.

Hopefully, someone can help.